# MVC 3 - How to RedirectToAction immediately after asynchronous WCF call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

How do i get my MVCcontroller method to call a long running WCF task asynchronously and redirect immediately after the asynchronously call is fired?

I have configured my WCF service reference to "Generate asynchronously operations" yet when the method is called i can see in the debugger that code steps through and **passes** the "RedirectToAction("RedirectToActionTestCompleted")" line but the browser does not redirect until the WCF task is finished.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult RedirectToActionTest()
    {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
        client.TestWcfCallAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("RedirectToActionTestCompleted");
    }

    public ActionResult RedirectToActionTestCompleted()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the WCF service method

```
public void TestWcfCall()
{
    Thread.Sleep(30000); //30 seconds
}
```

Why is the web page waiting for the WCF method to complete?

Comment: if you want to wait for the thread to finish before redirecting, then why it is asynchronous? No point...may as well make it synchronous.

Comment: The point is i don't want to wait.  It should fire and forget

Comment: but you say you want to "redirect when finished". That contradicts your above statement.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.  I wanted to know how to redirect immediately after the asynchronously call is fired.

Comment: @Fixed - Ok, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of asynchronous methods is that they should not block. Your test method is not asynchronous.

Use a true async WCF call and a async controller = nothing will block.

Comment: Yes, but is client.TestWcfCallAsync() not asynchronous?

Comment: If you do not want to wait on it, just do `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => client.TestWcfCallAsync());`. But do rename it since it's not async.

Answer (score 1):

Implement from AsyncController instead of Controller.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx

Comment: The Async controller will also block the thread from redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

Use a workflow solution like WF. The page can just start the workflow and return. The execution of the WCF task can then be managed by the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect immediately you're not interested in WCF call result in *the current http request*, right? If that's true you may want to use [OneWay operation call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733035.aspx). It will still block and if you really don't want to block even on OneWay calls you can [start it asyncronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx) - fire-and-forget scenario.